# Select row, use it, and mark as used

Tags: php, sql, row

I have a problem and need a direction to go.
After a customer pays in my webshop he receives an email. I got the mail and I need to put some PHP in.

I need to make a table in my database with unique numbers. Every one who gets a mail should get a unique number.

I'll try to explain the process I think it should go.

- read unique number from row in table
- paste number in mail
- mark row or unique number as used

How could I accomplish this. Any help would be welcome! :)

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: Indeed show us some work, some attempts at least. If you are just looking for someone to do it for you, hire a freelancer.

Comment: Have you considered adding a column, which is '0' if the number has been used and '1' if it has been used?

Comment: John en Puciek, i am sorry. i have been googling for a day and didnt build anything yet. I just hoped somebody could point me in a direction since its not easily googable. No pun intended.

Comment: Yes Refugnic i thought of that part. Any more useful tips? :)

Comment: You've got the mail and the prepopulation covered, yes? The database exists and you've got a supply of numbers, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your mail generation script, you could go about it like this:

```
SELECT `number` FROM `numbers` WHERE `used` = 0 LIMIT 1;
```

After fetching the result of this query, you put it into your mail and right before sending, you call this query:

```
UPDATE `numbers` SET `used` = 1 WHERE `number` = '$number';
```

Of course this assumes that each number is indeed unique (best enforced by keeping a `UNIQUE` or even `PRIMARY` key on that field `number`)...otherwise you would 'use' all entries with the same number.

Though you may want to consider using some encryption to convert an auto-incremental key into an alpha-numeric key.

If you need more help, we will need more information from you.

Comment: This can lead to numbers being used multiple times in a concurrent application (which a webapp generally is), so I'd be very careful with it.

Comment: @creinig I only answered the question of the OP. I agree that there are a number of better alternatives, but like this is the best way I can think of with the scenario the OP provided.

Comment: Well, the solution could be enhanced by e.g. (1) adding an "in use by" column, (2) first executing an `update numbers set in_use_by = <myself> where used = 0 and in_use_by is null`,  and (3) only continuing if a record was affected by that query. Or maybe using some other optimistic locking strategy. But most likely something simple like a sequence would be a better fit for the OP's problem.

Comment: Damn edit timeouts.  The thing in my previous comment of course doesn't work as described. A proper solution would be to extend *your* update stmt by an "and used = 0" and check whether any record was affected. Otherwise try the whole fetching cycle again.

Answer (score 0):

Unique numbers in a database are typically generated by *sequences*. Unless you have special requirements on the structure of these numbers this is simpler, faster and safer than pre-populating a table with numbers.